# multiple file upload's using ajax and spring boot alway return's null

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

When I try to upload multiple files, MultipartFile [] trainerProvider in the trainer controller is null.

Below is the code, please do help me out.

### trainer.jsp

```
$(function() {    $("form#data").submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var url  = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/eduskill/trainer/upload';

    var trainerProviderLogo = document.getElementById("trainingProviderLogo".files);

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("trainerProviderLogo", trainerProviderLogo);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (status) {
        // do something on success
       }
    });

    return false;

  });   });


<form id="data">
    <div class="form-inline row">
        <label class="col-md-4">Training Provider Logo:</label> <input
            class="col-md-5 new1-col" type="file"
            name="trainerProviderLogo[]" multiple="multiple"
            id="trainingProviderLogo" accept="image/*">
    </div>
</form>
```

### Trainer Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = { ControllerUriConstant.upload }, method = RequestMethod.POST)  public  @ResponseBody String becomeTrainer(             @RequestParam("trainerProviderLogo") MultipartFile[] trainerProviderLogo) throws IOException,           TechnoShineException { }
```

[Uploaded data from the ajax side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCrcl.png)